# Gluon Mobile FloatingActionButton (FAB) animation

Tags: mobile, javafxports, gluon

I managed to get a second FAB on the left side of the view.

```
commentFab.setFloatingActionButtonHandler(FloatingActionButton.BOTTOM_LEFT);
```

But it does so with an animation. How can I remove the animation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A FAB is intended for a primary action. Material Design [guidelines](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html) recommend just one FAB:

> Only one floating action button is recommended per screen to represent the most common action.

and with animation:

> It animates onto the screen as an expanding piece of material, by default.

Gluon's `FloatingActionButton` are designed with a translate animation when they are laid out after they are added to the View.

To avoid that transition, you could play with the fab's visibility: set it to false, create an pause transition, add the fab to the layer, and set the fab's visibility to true when the pause transition ends.

In my opinion, you should use a different `Layer` implementation.

Comment: I redesigned the layout in line with the Material Design guidelines and removed the second FAB. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction, it looks better now.